# Java Runtime.getRuntime() does not print any output or exit code

Tags: java, bash, kotlin

While running

send =   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myscript)

the script runs as intended but when I try to read any sort of output or exit code, I run into some problems

for example, if my .sh script is just the following two lines

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 10
```

printing send.exitValue() returns me exit code 0. Which is not what i am expecting.

This is also in fact after waiting for the program to finish with by using waitFor().

I am also attempting to read the input/output/error streams but they are all null with no values, with the following snippets

```
        val stdInput = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(send.inputStream))

        val stdError = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(send.errorStream))

        send.waitFor()
        println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n")
        var s: String? = null
        while (stdInput.readLine().also { s = it } != null) {
            println(s)
        }
        println("Here is the standard error of the command:\n")
        val e: String? = null
        while (stdError.readLine().also { s = it } != null) {
            println(e)
        }
```

The program I am writing is heavily dependent on the error codes to determine where the program failed if such a case happened. I cannot seem to find out how or why I get 0 as my exit code regardless

Comment: Your script does not use any streams as it has no output, so there will be nothing to read. To get this sorted out: you really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @g00se that is understandable. The error code is still a mystery to me as i shouldn't need any streams to get the exit status of the script

Comment: `val exitStatus = send.waitFor()`? This `waitFor()` should be at the bottom.